# Convert module to dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, module, namespaces

I would like to do the following (python3):

In module `settings.py`:

```
message = 'Hello'
```

In module `__main__.py`:

```
from . import settings


def dict_from_module(module):
    ...
    return d

print(dict_from_module(settings))
```

Running this should produce:

```
{'message': 'hello'}
```

Is there a canonical way of converting a module to a dictionary?

### EDIT

Using `vars(settings)` gives lots of internal information:

```
{   
    '__builtins__': {
        ...
    },
    '__cached__': 'xxx/__pycache__/settings.cpython-34.pyc',
    '__doc__': None,
    '__file__': 'xxx/settings.py',
    '__loader__': <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f87fc192518>,
    '__name__': 'xxx.settings',
    '__package__': 'xxx',
    '__spec__': ModuleSpec(...),
    'message': 'bye'
}
```

Which I do not want / need. I can filter that out (by removing keys starting with `__`), but I would like to avoid hacking around if there is an accepted way of doing this.

Comment: @vaultah: thanks, but that gives lots of internal attributes, which I do not want / need

Comment: I don't think there's a solution that doesn't include filtering out the predefined values in some way or another. Plus you need to resolve borderline cases, like what to do when module declares a variable `__doc__`.

Answer (score 10):

Hope this helps!

```
def dict_from_module(module):
    context = {}
    for setting in dir(module):
        # you can write your filter here
        if setting.islower() and setting.isalpha():
            context[setting] = getattr(module, setting)

    return context
```

Comment: My way: `module_to_dict = lambda module: {k: getattr(module, k) for k in dir(module) if not k.startswith('_')}`

Answer (score 3):

Anothoer option is to use `__all__` with module you with to convert to dict.
For example, my exported module is

```py
# mylib.py

__all__ = ['square']

def square(x):
    return x ** 2
```

And you can easily convert this module to dict like this:

```py
def module_to_dict(module):
    return {key: getattr(module, key) for key in module.__all__}
```

Giving the following output:

```py
>>> import mylib
>>> module_to_dict(mylib)
{'square': <function square at 0x03C39B28>}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a python file as a config file where I have constants and computable properties. And to interface with some web service I need it to be serializable (eg like a dictionary). Based on @heykarimoff 's solution, I used `startswith("_")` and `isinstance(v, ModuleType):` to filter out imported modules so that they won't show up in the dictionary.

```
def dict_from_module(module):
    context = {}
    for setting in dir(module):
        if not setting.startswith("_"):
            v = getattr(module, setting)
            if not isinstance(v, ModuleType):
                context[setting] = getattr(module, setting)
    return context
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import inspect
from itertools import takewhile

import .settings

dict(takewhile(lambda i: i[0] != '__builtins__', inspect.getmembers(settings)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is improved @heykarimoff answer, that I personally use.

```
# firstly I make a class attribute dict
class Ad(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self

# and now I make this function:
def m2d(module):
    return Ad({val: getattr(module, val) for val in dir(module) if '__' not in val})

import myModule

myDict = m2d(myModule) #our dictionary
```

As a result i receive a dictionary that acts like a module.
In opposite to a module though you can pass it easily to functions avoiding "Can't pickle module objects" error. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if `settings.py` content variable only:

settings.py:

```
   var1 = 'val1'
   var2 = 2
```

main.py:

```
from pprint import pprint
import settings
v={var:vars(settings)[var] for var in dir(settings) if not var.startswith('_')}
pprint(v)
```

```
{'var1': 'val1',
 'var2': 2}
```